# SR latch with two push buttons and one LED (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

What is wrong with my code ? I keep getting

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Im trying to build a `SR latch` with 2 push buttons  ,if the two push buttons are pressed the LED should be on LOW. And if either of them are pressed the LED should be able to stay on until it's reset by the other button

```
#include <arduinio.h>


const int buttonPin[] = {2,3};     // the number of the pushbutton pins
const int ledPin =  4;      // the number of the LED pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState1 = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonState2 = 0; 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  
  // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
  pinMode(2,INPUT);
  pinMode(3,INPUT);
}

void loop(){
 buttonState1 = digitalRead (2);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead (3);
  Serial.println(buttonState1);
  Serial.println(buttonState2);

  if (buttonState1 = 1 && buttonState2 = 0) {    
      // turn LED on:  
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
      else if (buttonState1 = 0 && buttonState2 = 1) {    
      // turn LED on:  
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else if (buttonState1 = 0 && buttonState2 = 0) {    
      // turn LED on:  
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
    else {    
      // turn LED on:  
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use = instead of == in *if* conditions. It should be like this:

```
if (buttonState1 == 1 && buttonState2 == 0) {}
```